# linking three dropdownbutton to get data from sharedpreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

Sir please want to know how to link a filter screen with a three dropdown button, whereby each of their dropdown menu showing data from a value of a key stored in shared preferences, also when the three selected and match the value in the shared preferences , it should print the key which holds the value and retrieve and display the data on a next screen when a done button is clicked. help me please, am a beginner learner ,wants to understand and explore or work efficiently. thank you God bless you.

Comment: please need an for my question please. any feedback